# Help with GDI+ image drawing

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, paint

I've recently taken my first step into GDI+, and am trying to draw an image from a bitmap. 
The code I have is this:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace Windowstuffs
{
    class AnimEngine : Form
    {
        public Graphics X;
        public Bitmap Y = new Bitmap(/* File Path */);

       void draw(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap Y = new Bitmap(/* File Path */);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Y, 0, 0);
            return;
        }

       public static void Main()
        {

            AnimEngine f1 = new AnimEngine();
            Application.Run(f1);
            f1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(f1.draw);
            f1.Refresh();
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

It compiles just fine, however, it doesn't draw anything. Everything else is completely functional, and after searching through MSDN and various tutorials, I still cannot find what I did wrong.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void Main()
{

    AnimEngine f1 = new AnimEngine();
    f1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(f1.draw);
    Application.Run(f1);
    f1.Refresh();
    return;
}
```

Just put the event subscription line above the Application.Run(f1) line :)

Comment: Thanks, but then how do I raise a Paint event after I first load the form?

Comment: you can call the Invalidate method of the control. [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx